# Página não carrega componentes Primefaces

Tags: java-ee, primefaces

Minha página não está carregando os componentes do Primefaces, no caso um dataTable. O resultado final está assim, tanto no chrome, quanto no próprio navegador do Eclipse:

[image: Lista de Marcas de Carro]

Segue o meu código:

**listaMarcas.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="m" value="#{marcaBean.listaMarcas}">
          <p:column headerText="Id">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{m.idMarca}"></p:outputLabel>
        </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Descrição">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{m.descMarca}"></p:outputLabel>
    </p:column> 
    <p:column headerText="Deletar"> 
        <h:commandLink value="Deletar" action="#{marcaBean.deletarMarca}">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{marcaBean.marca}" value="#{m}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
        </h:commandLink>
    </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>br.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>tesi2015</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>tesi2015 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8-02</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8-02</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>tesi2015</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>tesi2015</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Não sei se estou errando algo, já tentei de tudo e não consigo carregar a tabela. Como faço pra essa tabela aparecer? O que estou errando? Valeu.

Comment: Acho pertinente você editar sua pergunta e adicionar o conteúdo do seu arquivo `web.xml`.

Comment: Editado @electus

Comment: O que aparentemente ocorre é que tua aplicação está barrando os arquivos CSS que vem junto com o primefaces. Verifique se não implementou um filter, autenticação, algo do tipo...

Comment: Tentei adicionar o layout e não funcionou @Caffé

Comment: Ah, acho que lembrei :-) Você precisa de uma tag `head` porque é onde o primefaces adicionará código para referenciar suas bibliotecas. Experimente, antes de abrir a tag `<h:body>`, adicionar `<h:head> <title>Título da página</title> </h:head>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade os componentes Primefaces foram criados, ou você teria outros sintomas. O que ocorreu foi que os estilos não foram aplicados.

O **Primefaces** adiciona referências às suas bibliotecas de estilos (css) na tag **head**.

Se ele não encontra esta tag, acaba não adicionando as referências e sua página fica assim, sem estilo nenhum.

Para resolver o problema, simplesmente adicione a tag `head`. Seu código ficará mais ou menos assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Título da página (seção head necessária ao Primefaces)</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            ...
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```